# iOS 8 - Uitableviewcell edit items not displaying when swiped

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a custom UITableViewCell where everything is displaying correctly and I am able to swipe each row to the left.  On an iPad, everything works fine.  However on any model of iPhone, rather than display the two edit actions as defined in the code below, nothing is displayed.  The row simply slides to the left, leaving nothing where the edit buttons should be.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
    let thing = things![indexPath.row]

    var editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Edit") { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
        tableView.editing = false
        self.editThing = thing
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("thingEdit", sender: self)
    }
    editAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    var deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
        tableView.editing = false
        self.deleteThing(indexPath)
    }
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    return [editAction, deleteAction]
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
}
```

I am using essentially exactly the same code elsewhere and it works fine on all devices.  I have confirmed that there are no visible differences between the definition of the working and non-working tables in the storyboard.